# Exit journey when entering another journey - how to set up?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

hoping anyone can help me pointing me in the right direction here.

I have three journeys: we'll call them journey 1, 2 and 3 for sake of simplicity.

What I need to configure is the following: a contact is in journey 1. As soon as he enters journey 2, he should exit journey 1. When he enters journey 3 while he is still in journey 2, then he must exit journey 2.

The issue is of course that I can only use Contact Data in the Exit Criteria. Is there any way around this? Alternatively, I was thinking about adding true/false values on Contact level in SalesCloud and use that as Exit Criteria, but how do I then update the true/false flags when the customer is being exited from the journey...?

I've been searching on Stack Exchange, but haven't found any similar questions. I would really appreciate any advice on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new field in Sales Cloud for this.

You can do it this way:

1. Create a new (sendable) data extension that would record in which journey the contact is currently
2. Use Data Designer in Contact Builder to either create a new contact group or edit an existing one
3. Link you data extension to the Contact Key - this will make the data extension available as part of Contact Data
4. In your journeys add Update Contact Blocks and configure it like this at the minimum:
   [image]
   The `SubscriberKey` (or however you want to call it) needs to be dynamic for each of the people entering it and the way to get that in this block is by using data binding - you need to put this in the field: `{{Contact.Attribute."Contact"."Contact Key"}}`
5. Use this data extension as exit criteria, filters or decision splits in your other journeys

I described building a [basic journey log here](http://localhost:3000/sfmctipsandtrickschallenge/#creating-a-journey-log-with-the-the-update-contact-activity).